# Notation for conditional within a probability distribution

Tags: probability, variational-bayes

I'm reading an [excellent tutorial on variational autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf) by Carl Doersch. However, he uses the following notation to define the generative distribution:

$$ P(X|z;\theta) = N(X|f(z;\theta), \sigma^{2} * I) $$

I interpret this to mean that our reconstruction of the observed variable $X$ is a normal distribution with $\mu$ defined by some function $f(z;\theta)$ and covariance $\sigma^{2}$.

And he uses this notation to describe the latent deep Gaussian distribution on $Z$:

$$P(Z) = N(Z|0,I)$$

Which I interpret to mean that

> the latent variable Z is drawn from a (potentially multi-variate)
>   normal distribution with $\mu$ vector of 0 and covariance $I$.

I don't understand what the difference between the above and simply writing

$$P(Z) = N(0,I)$$ and

$$P(X|z;\theta) = N(f(z; \theta), \sigma^{2} * I) $$.

What is the difference conceptually? Is there any, or is it just a matter of style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the density notation in the paper. He reserves $\mathcal{N}(0,I)$ for referring to (normal) random variables (i.e. the distribution), and uses $\mathcal{N}(X|0,I)$ to refer to densities. For example, if $Z$ is distributed normally with zero-mean, identity covariance, we'd write $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$, (as is in Page 11). When we're talking about $p_Z(z)$, that is something like $\mathcal{N}(z|0,I)$ in the paper. However, notice that Eq. 12, I believe mistakenly, doesn't follow this convention. This notation is also prevalent in the original VAE paper of Kingma.